# Mysql data store with comma how to fetch separate word in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

In mysql database store data with comma when fetch result it show comma.
I want every word after comma hide and after comma word show separate in next line. and i can't want any changing in database because that database also connect with other code. only want changing in code .

***ScreenShot:***
  ([index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqkfw.png)
)
([connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsDFF.png) 
)
([Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vk8X.png) 
)
([Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beQwl.png)
)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No code=No help

Comment: You can split csv in php using `explode()`

Comment: Take a look at [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Don't post code as image. Never. That's a pain to read and we can't copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are fetching the data, explode the string containing comma. like so-

```
$a=explode(',',$row['keyword']);
  foreach($a as $keyword)
  {
    echo $keyword;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will do the job for you.

```
$searchTerms = "Blue iconer, Web design, Tester";
$searchTermsArrayTemp = explode(",", $searchTerms); //build an array exploding the string using comma delimiter.
$searchTermsArray = array_map('trim', $searchTermsArrayTemp); //remove the unwanted trailing and leading spaces.
foreach ($searchTermsArray AS $searchTerm)
{
    echo $searchTerm;
}

/*
 * Blue iconer
 * Web design
 * Tester
 */
```

---

Personally, I woulnd't build the database that way, that will be a pain to remove/add/edit a keyword, and some keyword can be redundant on others business ([DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

I would use a separate table for keywords :

**keyword**

```
id | word
---+------------
1  | Blue iconer
2  | Web design
3  | Tester
```

One business can have 1 or more keywords **(1, n)**

One keyword can have 1 or more business **(1, n)**

You have a Many-To-Many relation between both tables, that results an intermediate table *businesskeywords*

**businesskeywords**

```
business_id | keyword_id
------------+------------
5           | 1
5           | 2
5           | 3
```

What keywords have the business of id 5?

```
SELECT keyword.word
FROM keyword
INNER JOIN businesskeywords ON businesskeywords.keyword_id = keyword.id
WHERE businesskeywords.business_id = 5
```

What business have the keyword *Tester*?

```
SELECT business.id_business, business.name
FROM business
INNER JOIN businesskeywords ON businesskeywords.business_id = business.id_business
INNER JOIN businesskeywords ON businesskeywords.keyword_id = keyword.id
WHERE keyword.word LIKE '%Tester%'
```